# Function calls from iterator loops "Debug assertion failed" Expression:map/set iterators incompatible

Tags: c++, iterator

Function calls from iterator loops

I am getting an error when calling a function from inside an iterator loop saying "Debug assertion failed" Expression:map/set iterators incompatible. Not sure what the reason is.

```
char *text = new char[MAXLEN];
int j;
for( map<int, string>::iterator it=map.begin(); it!=map.end(); ++it)
{
    for (j=0;j<orows;j++)
    {
        strcpy(text, (*it).second.c_str());
        char val;
        obj->FindStatus(data[j].id, stripback, &val);
        data[j].status[j] = val;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Calling your `map` `map` is perhaps a bad idea, no? 2. What is the type of `map`? (the one you call `map.begin()` on).

Comment: map is <int, string>. Please not that the obj->FindStatus is a call to a COM object. Also found this http://aprogrammers.blogspot.ca/2009/10/mapset-iterators-incompatible.html which suggests that somehow the mutex on the iterators is corrupted

Comment: How long is the char array returned by `c_str`? I don't think you'll get away with just copying over the top of it without taking its size into account. Undefined behaviour looms (and might be being observed (c;).

Comment: it is less than the size of the "text" char array. I can tell you that for sure.

Comment: Is this the real code? Make a full working example, which should only be a few more lines of code, which we can try out. See [sscce](http://sscce.org).